# touchesBegan If Statement Problems

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to detect whether or not a node is an enemy or not. If it is, I want to remove it. I'm attempting to use the touched nodes name to detect this. I am able to detect whether or not the node's name is enemy, but I don't know how to remove it. Thanks for the help! :)

Here's all relevant code:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first!
    let location = touch.location(in: self)
    let nodes = self.nodes(at: location);
    let name = nodes.first?.name;

    if (name == "enemy") {
        nodes.removeFromParent() // this doesn't work
    }
}

@objc open func spawnEnemies() {
    let randomNumber = randomBetween(min: Int(-150), max: Int(self.frame.width + 150))
    print(randomNumber)
    print(self.frame.width)
    var enemy = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "triangle")
    enemy.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(randomNumber), y: self.frame.height + 250)
    enemy.name = "enemy";
    enemy.zPosition = 6.0;

    enemy.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

    enemy.zRotation = 0
    enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: enemy.texture!, size: enemy.texture!.size())
    enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    enemy.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
    enemy.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = enemyCategory
    enemy.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = blockerCategory
    enemy.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = blockerCategory
    enemy.setScale(CGFloat(0.03))
    addChild(enemy)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part of your code is problematic:

```
let nodes = self.nodes(at: location);
let name = nodes.first?.name;

if (name == "enemy") {
    nodes.removeFromParent() // this doesn't work
}
```

Your variable `nodes` is an **array** of `SKNode` instances; it doesn't make any sense to call the `SKNode` method `removeFromParent()` on the whole array (only on its individual *elements*).

You have successfully tested the name of the `.first` element; do the same to remove it:

```
let nodes = self.nodes(at: location);
let name = nodes.first?.name;

if (name == "enemy") {
    nodes.first?.removeFromParent()
}
```

Or perhaps a better apporach (removes multiple enemies in one round):

```
for node in self.nodes(at: location) {
    if node.name == "enemy" {
        node.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

Finally, a more "swifty" version of the code above:

```
nodes.filter({ (node) -> Bool in
    return node.name == "enemy"
}).forEach({ (enemy) in
    enemy.removeFromParent()
})
```